# MVC / Bootstrap - Radio Button in group not selecting on initialisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an edit form in my MVC application that has a Traffic Light Status.

When the form is initially opened, the check mark on the "lights" always set to "green" despite jQuery code to set otherwise.

All the code is firing, but it just does not set the initial state.

In this simplified example, if the Model's AlertLevel is set to "Red", the "tick" is still on the "green"

**Markup**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AlertLevel)
<span class="btn-group RAGStatus" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-success active " style="width:50px; height: 30px">
        <input type="radio" name="ragStatus" id="ragButton_Green" autocomplete="off" value="Green">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hidden unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok checked"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-warning" style="width:50px; height: 30px">
        <input type="radio" name="ragStatus" id="ragButton_Amber" autocomplete="off" value="Amber">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hidden unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok checked"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger" style="width:50px; height: 30px">
        <input type="radio" name="ragStatus" id="ragButton_Red" autocomplete="off" value="Red">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hidden unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok checked"></span>
    </label>
</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var status = $("#AlertLevel").val();
    $('#ragButton_' + status).prop("checked", true);
})
```

**Model**

```
public class DeptStatus
{
    public string AlertLevel { get; set; }
}
```

**CSS** (for the glyph icon display)

```
.RAGStatus .checked {
    display: none;
}

.RAGStatus .active .checked {
    display: inline-block;
}

.RAGStatus .active .unchecked {
    display: none;
}
```

**Update**

In a follow on jQuery function (removed from example), if I do `var ragStatus = $('input[name=ragStatus]:checked').val();` then it returns "Red"

Comment: Do you mean that `AlertLevel` has a value when the view is loaded but the corresponding radio button is not selected when loaded?

Comment: Your edit means that the script for setting the `checked` property is working (although you script is unnecessary is you use the `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` method to generate the html). I assume this is an issue with `<span>` elements and/or css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like bootstrap adds a `active` class to the container.

try

```
$(function () {
    var status = $("#AlertLevel").val();
    $('#ragButton_' + status).trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to rely on jQuery to select the initial value of the button group as razor will be able to do this for you, so in your case:

```
<span class="btn-group RAGStatus" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-success active " style="width:50px; height: 30px">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AlertLevel, "Green", new { autocomplete = "off" })
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hidden unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok checked"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-warning" style="width:50px; height: 30px">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AlertLevel, "Amber", new { autocomplete = "off" })
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hidden unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok checked"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger" style="width:50px; height: 30px">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AlertLevel, "Red", new { autocomplete = "off" })
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hidden unchecked"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok checked"></span>
    </label>
</span>
```

Comment: Well, I can certainly see in the debug console that the html is being generated correctly `<input autocomplete="off" checked="checked" id="AlertLevelx" name="AlertLevelx" type="radio" value="Red" />` but it still puts the tick mark on the green button (Useful answer, but hasn't solved the problem)

Comment: Could you add the rendered HTML to your question please?

Answer (score 0):

What if you add:

```
$('#ragButton_' + status).attr('checked', 'checked);
```

It might have some problems with `prop` function due to version of jQuery.